# Why do people need more reputation for EL&U for the same privileges than on some other SE sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation

For instance, my 500+ reputation would allow me to cast close and open votes on a number of Stackexchange sites. Here, it requires 3000. Why is that?

Answer (score 13):

Those sites are in [beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta) and thus have relaxed rep requirements. ELU is [graduated](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=launched). Check out Math, another graduated site you're registered on — it, too, requires 3k rep to cast close and reopen votes.

For details, see the meta-Meta post "[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)", and the blog post "[When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)".

Comment: So that's why we have two directories? One for beta and one for "graduated?" What does it take to graduate?

Comment: See [When Will My Site Graduate?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/) I am adding this to the answer.